# Why do Dense layers perform better than a mix of Conv Layers, Recurrent Layers on Sentiment Analysis with BERT emebddings?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp, recurrent-neural-network

I have used BERT to make embeddings out of the imdb review dataset and I am trying out some models to check their perfomance on sentiment analysis (0 for the bad reviews and 1 for the good ones). I have seen that models with just dense Layers do work better than models which are a mixture of Convolutional with MaxPooling Layers and recurrent units such as LSTM or BiLSTM.I want to know why is this happening since BERT do captures of semantics and time dependencies so second models should perform better. I am speaking about orders from 85% accuracy with dense layers to 75% with the mix of Layers. Thanks in adavance

Comment: Dense layer on CLS token?

Comment: Hello, what is a CLS token?

Comment: Where did you apply MLP on?

Comment: Nowhere. Are you talking about multilinear pereceptron?

Comment: Yes,s because you have mentioned about Dense layer (MLP or Multi-Layer Perceptron) working better than CNN and LSTM. So, what was the input to these models or where did you place these layers in your model?

Comment: I have used Bert embeddings for the imdb reviews dataset. So i have 50K samples of reviews translated to vectors of 768 components. And out of that I want to train a model for sentiment clasification 0 for bad reviews, and 1 for the possitive ones.

Comment: So, It's just 1* 768 for a sample?

Comment: Yes, but I reshape into tensor form to be fed for convs and rnns.

Comment: So, most likely you are using the 1st token only, (CLS token). Which is usually enough for the classification, as it has captured the entire sentence representation. In which case, CNN and RNN makes no sense. Thus a simple Dense layer is sufficient for the classification.

Comment: That is interesting, but I can not get to understand you. By doing this 
x_train1 = np.array(x_train).reshape(-1, 768, 1) you mean the sequences are just trained number by number? Indeed that would be the reason why recurrent nns would have no sense. What do you think? Thanks a lot

Comment: Something like doing a reshape(-1,768, 5)? But I have to transform the targets as well and I do not know how to

Comment: Just imaging you want to train sequence of words (max of 200 words), and each word has embeddings of length 300, then you'll have (-1, 200, 300) right? Now RNN or CNN makes sense as you have sequence of 200 words. But imagine you have only 1 word in the entire sequence (basically not a sequence). Now, RNN or CNN cannot be used in the way it is meant to be used.

Comment: Yes but since I got embeddings from BERT and it converts all the sequences into a 768 dimension problem I do not know how many numbers correspond to each word. So, you are saying that in this case it is not a good choice to use convs or rnns? But then, in any problem it would be helpfull. Because you always need to make embeddings or an embeddings layer that you do not know how it turns the words into numbers.

Comment: You can get the complete sequence of embeddings. I am not sure what API you are using to extract the embeddings.

Comment: I am using this API: https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/tree/master/examples/datasets
It returns a whole 768 embedding for a sentence. The things is that I do not know how many components are a token so in no case CNN or LSTMs would be helpful for this kind of embedding in your opinion, right? Cause I can not set the correct third dimension of the input tensor.

Comment: Yes, if it's sentence embeddings, no point of using CNN or RNN

Comment: All right, that is am important lesson for me. Thanks a lot my friend.